# Android keyboard with speech-to-text that does not use Google services

Tags: android, speech-recognition, keyboard, virtual-keyboard

I am looking for an Android keyboard that has quick access to speech-to-text functionality, but that does not require any Google services or software.

[TouchPal](http://www.touchpal.com/android.html) looks like a good keyboard, but it requires Google's speech-to-text software, so it's a no-go.

Prefer [gratis](/questions/tagged/gratis), but paid is acceptable.  Must be KitKat compatible.

Can anyone recommend one?

***UPDATE:*** I forgot to include a key requirement: that the keyboard and speech-to-text functionality work [offline](/questions/tagged/offline).  Thus, I created [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/26841/android-keyboard-with-offline-speech-to-text-that-does-not-use-google-services) seeking recommendations that include that additional requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Swype*** seems pretty awesome. It has *Dragon dictation* instead for voice recognition:

> Swype comes with best-in-class voice recognition so you can go hands-free and dictate text quickly with a simple press of the voice key on the Swype keyboard.

They have a [free trial version](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nuance.swype.trial) available; the [full version](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nuance.swype.dtc) can be obtained for ~USD 1.

Note for other readers: *Swype* is not yet ready for Marshmallow (Android 6), but they are reportedly working on it.

Comment: Note: I've enriched the answer with some details. *Dragon* is in fact known to be of high quality. It's based on the [Dragon NaturallySpeaking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_NaturallySpeaking) engine, built by the same company as *Swype.* The probably best known product using it is Apple's *Siri*. Also see: [Wikipedia on Dragon Dictation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Dictation).