# Android keyboard with *offline* speech-to-text that does not use Google services

Tags: android, offline, speech-recognition, keyboard, virtual-keyboard

I wrote [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/26732/android-keyboard-with-speech-to-text-that-does-not-use-google-services), and it received a good valid answer.

Unfortunately, I did not include a key requirement, and that answer does not satisfy the requirement.  My mistake.

Since that question already has a good answer, I will pose a similar question, this time adding the key requirement: that the keyboard and speech-to-text functionality both work completely [offline](/questions/tagged/offline).

***So here's what I'm seeking:***

An [android](/questions/tagged/android) [keyboard](/questions/tagged/keyboard) that has quick access to speech-to-text (aka [speech-recognition](/questions/tagged/speech-recognition) or voice-to-text) functionality, but that does not require any Google services or software.  Must work completely [offline](/questions/tagged/offline).

Two apps that I have tested, but do not qualify:

- [TouchPal](http://www.touchpal.com/android.html) looks like a good keyboard, but it requires Google's speech-to-text software, so it's a no-go.
- [Swype](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nuance.swype.trial) requires an active internet connection for the speech-to-text functionality to work, so it's a no-go as well.

Prefer [gratis](/questions/tagged/gratis), but paid is acceptable.  Must be KitKat compatible.

Can anyone recommend one?

***Update:*** As previously stated, this is similar to another question, but not a duplicate.  This question adds a specific requirement not present in the other question.  The accepted answer to that question does not satisfy the requirements of this question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android keyboard with speech-to-text that does not use Google services](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/26732/android-keyboard-with-speech-to-text-that-does-not-use-google-services)

Comment: As discussed above, that is a similar question, but the requirements are different.

Comment: Five years later... Did you find a solution?

Comment: @kyb Unfortunately, I have not, nor have I yet to receive any answers to this question.  Because I have not found an offline speech-recognition keyboard for Android, my ability to enter text in Android is still very limited (unless I want to connect a keyboard, but that's too much of a hassle every time I want to enter text).  It's largely because of this that I really don't get much use out of Android.  If I can't easily enter data, it's pretty much only usable for one-way applications.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: afaik there is still no app, but open source backends now exist, so <s>maybe it is easy to wrap it in a keyboard application</s> *I've started to build a [prototype](https://github.com/Felicis/vosk-android-demo).*

About 5 years ago I discovered voice typing by google and enjoyed it very much. Then I banned google from my phone and had since to arrange without voice typing. Back then there weren't any open source projects for voice typing which were good and small enough to be used in an android app, so I abandoned the wish.

Today, though, there is pocketsphinx and kaldi which have decent "small" models for several languages and it seems even mozilla is working on something to be released in near future. I've just tried vosk (based on kaldi), which has a [demo android app](https://github.com/alphacep/vosk-android-demo/) (sources, not apk) and models (<100MB) for multiple languages which can be plugged together easily. Building on this it should be possible to create a keyboard app with offline speech-to-text to be used with other apps, like the google one. Currently the models are also worse than google's, so expect many errors, but it would be easy to update with better models later on.

PS: I'm going to try building a prototype keyboard to see if it is usable yet. I'll let you know.

Comment: Thank you for all the details.  I really look forward to your future updates with a link to your prototype!  I wonder if something could be built to work *in conjunction* with existing non-voice keyboard apps.  For open-source Android keyboard apps, I find AnySoftKeyboard (https://github.com/AnySoftKeyboard/AnySoftKeyboard) to currently be the best, but it's gesture support needs more love.  I find the best gesture support in a non-Google keyboard app is with SwiftKey.  A non-Google keyboard with offline voice recognition and great gesture support will be nothing short of amazing.

Comment: Here's the link to the prototype: https://github.com/Felicis/vosk-android-demo I haven't added an apk yet, so right now you need to build it yourself, but I will add one soon

Comment: Now I have added apks for english and german models.

Comment: Thank you for keeping us all updated on your progress Fabio!